# Pay-Pal / No Order confirmation is sent

Tags: paypal, order-confirmation

After updating to Magento 1.9.1.0 there are no order confirmations sent when a customer pays throug PayPal. Every other payment works fine, also PayPal was working fine before I updated.

I receive the payment and a payment notification from PayPal. Orders are registered but the status stays on "Pending Payment" even though payment was made. Before it changed to "Processing"

I have found no solution around the web, that helped. The IPN is configured and after payment the customer gets redirected to the shop.

Edit: There seems to be a problem with the IPN: PayPal redirects to https://SHOPNAME/paypal/ipn. I think it should actually be http://SHOPNAME/paypal/ipn. In the PayPal-Settings the version with http is displayed.